# How to hide code coverage information in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to hide the code coverage data in the project tree view but keep the window tab button at the bottom right for when I want to check it? I don't want to clutter the project structure view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in IntelliJ IDEA to hide the code coverage in Project View, please follow/comment the related issue about providing less verbose coverage:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-37534